# "Closed subsets of compact space are compact" with an alternative definition of covering

Tags: general-topology

I am studying Abraham and Marsden's *Foundations of Mechanics*. They define a covering $\{U_\alpha\}$ of a set $S$ to satisfy $S = \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$, and **NOT** as $S\subseteq\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$.

Their definitions of compactness of a topological space, and its subsets (involving the relative topology) are the usual ones.

Then they casually remark

> It follows easily that a closed subset of a compact space is compact.

However, I'm not able to prove this with the given definition of cover. (I can prove it using the latter definition though.)

I'm even skeptical if that holds with the given definition.

---

**I really don't think that this is a duplicate!**

Comment: In which topology are the $U_\alpha$ open?  (Authors who use set equality for open covers often use open sets in the subspace topology, in which case the two definitions are equivalent)

Comment: @BrianMoehring If an open cover of $S$, then they are open in the topological space $S$. If open cover for a subset of $S$, then open in the relative topology of that subset.

Comment: If we use that definition (open in the relative topology) , can you see why $S \subsetneq \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$ is impossible? (Since $U_\alpha \subseteq S$ for every $\alpha$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes, because $U_\alpha$'s are the subsets of $S$. But what does this lead to?

Comment: This means the two definitions are equivalent in the relative topology.

Comment: @BrianMoehring But that's only when you are looking at covers of $S$ (not its subsets). Isn't it?

Comment: It seems that you expect that the "correct" definition of compactness of a subset $S \subset X$ is that each cover of $S$ with open subsets of $X$ has  a finite subcover of $S$ - but this is in fact a *property* of compact subsets. I think you mean that the compactness of closed subsets can easily proved using this property, but as it stands it could be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea is to "lift" each element of your cover of $S$ to a cover of your ambient space.  Since you seem to be struggle to intuit how that works from the usual proof, here is a full proof with details.

Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ be an open cover of $S\subseteq X$; that is, each $U_{\alpha}$ is open *in the subspace topology* on $S$ induced by $X$, and such that $$\bigcup_{\alpha}{U_{\alpha}}=S$$

Fix $\alpha$.  Since $U_{\alpha}$ is open in the subspace topology induced by $X$, there exists an set $V_{\alpha}\supseteq U_{\alpha}$ such that $V_{\alpha}\subseteq X$ is open (in the natural topology on $X$) and $V_{\alpha}\cap S=U_{\alpha}$.

Now vary $\alpha$, and consider the collection made by combining $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ with $\{X\setminus S\}$.  Each element in this collection is open in $X$ and \begin{align*}
X&=(X\setminus S)\cup S \\
&=(X\setminus S)\cup\bigcup_{\alpha}{U_{\alpha}} \\
&\subseteq(X\setminus S)\cup\bigcup_{\alpha}{V_{\alpha}} \\
&\subseteq X\cup\bigcup_{\alpha}{X} \\
&=X
\end{align*}  Thus all these sets are equal.  In particular, $$X=(X\setminus S)\cup\bigcup_{\alpha}{V_{\alpha}}$$

So our new collection is an open cover of $X$.  Since $X$ is compact, it has a finite subcover; say, $\{V_{\beta}\}_{\beta}$, possibly combined with $\{X\setminus S\}$.  But then \begin{align*}
S&=X\cap S \\
&=((X\setminus S)\cup\bigcup_{\beta}{V_{\beta}})\cap S \\
&=((X\setminus S)\cap S)\cup\bigcup_{\beta}{(V_{\beta}\cap S)} \\
&=\emptyset\cup\bigcup_{\beta}{U_{\beta}} \\
&=\bigcup_{\beta}{U_{\beta}}
\end{align*}  Thus $\{U_{\beta}\}_{\beta}$ is a finite open cover of $S$.

Comment: Nice proof. You use the axiom of choice to associate to each $U_\alpha \subset X$ an open $V_\alpha  \subset X$. You can avoid this by taking as an open cover of $X$ all open $V \subset X$ such that $V \cap S \in \{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ plus $X \setminus S$.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Ooh, nice!  I don't usually try to avoid choice (I do a lot of analysis), but that's a good trick.