# "Closed subsets of compact space are compact" with an alternative definition of covering.

Tags: general-topology

**NOTE:** I am reposting this question as this was [deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091772/673223), claimed being a duplicate. However, please note that this is **not**, as the question doesn't at all talk of how the statement holds if we assume the alternative definition below, which is entirely what I ask. **Before closing this again, please look carefully.**

---

I am studying Abraham and Marsden's *Foundations of Mechanics*. They define a covering $\{U_\alpha\}$ of a set $S$ to satisfy $S = \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$, and **NOT** $S\subseteq\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$.

Their definitions of compactness of a topological space, and its subsets (involving the relative topology) are the usual ones.

Then they casually remark

> It follows easily that a closed subset of a compact space is compact.

However, I'm not able to prove this with the given definition of cover. (I can prove it using the latter definition though.)

I'm even skeptical if that holds with the given definition.

---

**Got an answer!** User Vercassivelaunos's comment below answers the question.

Comment: Hint: Use the topologie restricted to the closed subset. With this topologie the same proof works (with the obvious modifications)

Comment: Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be an open covering of the closed set $C\subseteq S$, where $S$ is compact. Then there are open sets $\{\tilde U_\alpha\}$ such that $U_\alpha=U_\alpha\cap C$. Now $\{S\backslash C\}\cup\{\tilde U_\alpha\}$ is an open cover of $S$, and thus admits a finite subcover. Intersect all of the covering sets with $C$ and if necessary remove the empty set ($C\cap(S\backslash C)=\emptyset$) to get a finite subcover of $\{U_\alpha\}$.

Comment: Have you tried proving the equivalence of the definitions? As Vercassivelaunos writes, it is an exercise in using the subspace topology $\tau_A = \{O \cap A \mid O \in \tau_X\}$ for topological space $(X, \tau_X)$ and $A \subset X$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks tons for your answer! It didn't occur to me that I could take the intersections of $\tilde U_\alpha$'s with $A$ again. Thanks and kudos!

Comment: [The original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091772/closed-subsets-of-compact-space-are-compact-with-an-alternative-definition-of) has been undeleted and reopened, so I have closed this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks! Appreciate it.